# ws-security with CXF using interceptors

Tags: java, cxf

I'm trying to learn CXF and want to implement ws security with a simple hello world example. 
I followed bottom up approach to create a cxf service which is runing and I tested with soap ui. I wrote a spring client and it is working fine too.

Then I tried to add the timestamp. I added
the WSS4J and saaj interceptors in both server and clent spring bean config files. I followed this blog.

[cxf-spring-and-ws-security-putting-it](http://domagojtechtips.blogspot.com/2007/08/cxf-spring-and-ws-security-putting-it.html)

I exactly followed the same steps and I added timestamp action. When I run the client I get this

I get this exception

```
org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: An error was discovered processing the 
<wsse:Security> header
```

My wsdl does not have any entries concerning the security or the interceptors I added.

The SOAP request is the same as the one before interceptors were added. I figured out that the  header is missing from the request. How can I add  header in the request in this scenario?

Please check below for stack trace.

```
ID: 4
Address: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldWithSecurity/services/HelloWorldImplPort
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
Headers: {accept-encoding=[gzip,deflate], connection=[Keep-Alive], Content-Length=[294], content-type=[text/xml;charset=UTF-8], host=[localhost:8080], SOAPAction=[""], user-agent=[Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)]}
Payload: <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.spring.demo/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:sayHi>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>Yamini</arg0>
      </ser:sayHi>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
Sep 21, 2012 10:53:51 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor checkActions
WARNING: Security processing failed (actions mismatch)
Sep 21, 2012 10:53:51 AM org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor handleMessage
WARNING: 
org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.checkActions(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:359)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:312)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:209)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Sep 21, 2012 10:53:51 AM org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doDefaultLogging
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://service.spring.demo/}HelloWorldImplService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.createSoapFault(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:733)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:333)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:207)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:209)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:191)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:185)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:108)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1001)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.checkActions(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:359)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:312)
    ... 27 more
Sep 21, 2012 10:53:51 AM org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractLoggingInterceptor log
INFO: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 4
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode xmlns:ns1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">ns1:InvalidSecurity</faultcode><faultstring>An error was discovered processing the &lt;wsse:Security> header</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
Sep 21, 2012 11:31:29 AM org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractLoggingInterceptor log
INFO: Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 5
Address: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldWithSecurity/services/HelloWorldImplPort
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Headers: {Accept=[*/*], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[610], content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8], host=[localhost:8080], pragma=[no-cache], SOAPAction=[""], user-agent=[Apache CXF 2.4.9]}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header><wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1"><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-1"><wsu:Created>2012-09-21T16:31:29.958Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2012-09-21T16:36:29.958Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security></soap:Header><soap:Body><ns2:sayHi xmlns:ns2="http://service.spring.demo/"><arg0>Yamini</arg0></ns2:sayHi></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
sayHi called
Sep 21, 2012 11:31:29 AM org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractLoggingInterceptor log
INFO: Outbound Message
---------------------------
ID: 5
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:sayHiResponse xmlns:ns2="http://service.spring.demo/"><return>Hello   Yamini</return></ns2:sayHiResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
```

I do not see any security headers in the request. So I'm getting the exception when the response is getting processed for them. What I want to get an idea is how to add security headers in the case when the web service is developed in java first approach.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you provide a log or stack trace?

Comment: looks like your spring beans for interceptor are not correctly created or bound to your client. We had exactly the same exception : it says "a problem was discovered processing the wsse header" even if the header does not exist at all ! (and that was our case since we did not create it. We do so using java code, not spring)

Answer (score 5):

Your header should look like this...

```
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="UsernameToken-2">
            <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

Comment: Why should it?  Please explain in case the OP doesn't have as much experience here.

Comment: Basically WS-Security is message level authentication and authorization unlike transport-level only scheme HTTP BASIC. WSS4J provides the interceptors using which you can easily add the authentication, authorization, Integrity and confidentiality data into the SOAP message. If you are using the java client like shown in the code below it will auto inject all the variable for you. In your case it is not able to the soap header required tags to check the credentials. That is its failing to even validate the request against the schema aganist which the server is trying to validate.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to add wsse:Security header in your SOAP request

```
<soapenv:envelope ...
     <soapenv:header>
        <wsse:security soapenv:mustunderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
          <wsse:usernametoken wsu:id="UsernameToken-27777511" xmlns:wsu="http://Pdocs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
          <wsse:username>admin</wsse:username>
          <wsse:password type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pass</wsse:password>
         </wsse:usernametoken>
        </wsse:security>
       </soapenv:header>

<soapenv:body>
--
   </soapenv:body>
</soapenv:envelope>
```